# Avoid Table column duplicate value

Tags: javascript

I have a script, that checks for column duplication in my html tables's column. 
If yes it is displaying an error span and delete the field's value

```
$('[name="numbers[]"]').on("input", function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('[name="numbers[]"]')
    .not(this)
    .each(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == value) {
        document.getElementById("error").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("numbers[]").value = "";
      }
    });
});
```

I have only 3 problem with it.

*1. I want to run only when I leave the watched field. **(Update:Solved)**
*2. I don't have unique ids (numbers[]). When it delete the field it delete the first id that it find not that I want. **(Update: Not so important)**
3. I want to check for duplication and zero too

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nzlorca/w3ugevt6)

Sorry for my English ;)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="hu">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>       
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive mx-auto" id="zonaTable">
               <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                     <th class="text-center" style="width:5%">Numbers</th>
                     <th class="text-center" style="width:15%">Locations</th>
                     <th class="text-center" style="width:30%">Description</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
               <div class="alert" id="error" style="display: none;">
                  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
                  <strong>ERROR! </strong>The number must be unique!
               </div>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="number" class="text-center align-middle form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="3" id="zona_szam[]" name="zona_szam[]" value="1"></td>
                     <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="Zones" name="Zones">
                           <option selected disabled></option>
                           <label>Zones</label>
                           <option value="example1">example1</option>
                           <option value="example2">example2</option>
                           <option value="example3">example3</option>
                           <option value="example4">example4</option>
                           <option value="example5">example5</option>
                           <option value="example6">example6</option>
                           <option value="example7">example7</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="35" id="zona_leiras[]" name="zona_leiras[]"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="number" class="text-center align-middle form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="3"  id="zona_szam[]" name="zona_szam[]" value="2"></td>
                     <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="Zones" name="Zones">
                           <option selected disabled></option>
                           <label>Zones</label>
                           <option value="example1">example1</option>
                           <option value="example2">example2</option>
                           <option value="example3">example3</option>
                           <option value="example4">example4</option>
                           <option value="example5">example5</option>
                           <option value="example6">example6</option>
                           <option value="example7">example7</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="35" id="zona_leiras[]" name="zona_leiras[]"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="number" class="text-center align-middle form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="3"  id="zona_szam[]" name="zona_szam[]" value="3"></td>
                     <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="Zones" name="Zones">
                           <option selected disabled></option>
                           <label>Zones</label>
                           <option value="example1">example1</option>
                           <option value="example2">example2</option>
                           <option value="example3">example3</option>
                           <option value="example4">example4</option>
                           <option value="example5">example5</option>
                           <option value="example6">example6</option>
                           <option value="example7">example7</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="35" id="zona_leiras[]" name="zona_leiras[]"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="number" class="text-center align-middle form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="3"  id="zona_szam[]" name="zona_szam[]" value="4"></td>
                     <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="Zones" name="Zones">
                           <option selected disabled></option>
                           <label>Zones</label>
                           <option value="example1">example1</option>
                           <option value="example2">example2</option>
                           <option value="example3">example3</option>
                           <option value="example4">example4</option>
                           <option value="example5">example5</option>
                           <option value="example6">example6</option>
                           <option value="example7">example7</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="35" id="zona_leiras[]" name="zona_leiras[]"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="number" class="text-center align-middle form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="3"  id="zona_szam[]" name="zona_szam[]" value="" ></td>
                     <td>
                        <select class="form-control" id="Zones" name="Zones">
                           <option selected disabled></option>
                           <label>Zones</label>
                           <option value="example1">example1</option>
                           <option value="example2">example2</option>
                           <option value="example3">example3</option>
                           <option value="example4">example4</option>
                           <option value="example5">example5</option>
                           <option value="example6">example6</option>
                           <option value="example7">example7</option>
                        </select>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="35" id="zona_leiras[]" name="zona_leiras[]"></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="no-print form-group col-md-3">                    
               <input class="form-control" type="number" id="insert-rows-amnt" placeholder="How many Rows?">
            </div>
            <div class="no-print form-group col-md-2">                    
               <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="add-row" value="Add rows">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .closebtn {
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  .closebtn:hover {
    color: black;
  }
```

JS:

```
//check duplicates in table column        
        $('[name="zona_szam[]"]').on('input',function(){
          var value = $(this).val();
          $('[name="zona_szam[]"]').not(this).each(function(){
             if($(this).val() == value) {
               document.getElementById("error").style.display= '';               
             }
          }) 
        });
        
//add rows to table        
        $('#add-row').click(function() {
          var $tbody, $row, additionalRows;
          var numNewRows = parseInt($('#insert-rows-amnt').val(), 10);
            
          if (isNaN(numNewRows) || numNewRows <= 0) {
            alert('How many rows do you like to add');
          } else {
        
            $tbody = $('#zonaTable tbody');
            $row = $tbody.find('tr:last');
        
            additionalRows = new Array(numNewRows + 1).join($row[0].outerHTML);
        
            $tbody.append(additionalRows);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: 1. Replace `input` with `blur` or `change``

Comment: 2. IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, so if yours currently aren't, that is the first thing you will have to fix.

Comment: I know that must be unique, but how can i do that if I don't know how many rows will be if i submit the form? (the user can add rows to the table)

Comment: What exactly do you even need IDs for? I already asked you to please provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue - which you still have not done, so the context of this is still quite unclear.

Comment: Which field's value do you want to delete - that of the _current_ field, that the event occurred upon to begin with? Then what do you want with any IDs for that? You are already accessing that very field using `$(this)`.

Comment: Ok sorry here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nzlorca/w3ugevt6/

Comment: The site I linked to _also_ explains, that all relevant information is supposed to be contained directly in the question itself - so please put it in there, instead of just dumping it onto an external platform.

Comment: Ok 1. problem solved.
I use  "change" event instead of "input"

Comment: Then please answer the question I asked you, regarding the second problem.

Comment: By zero you mean the character `0` entered into the field? So go check if `$(this).val() == "0"` then. Or more than that, is it supposed to cover `0.0` or `.0` and similar as well?

Comment: Yes As you can write, i want to delete the field where the event occurred.

Comment: Yes It is forbidden the duplicate numbers and the 0 character

Comment: Ok I understand the $(this).val() == "0" but I'm noob in javascript... too.... ;)
I tried that but not working:
if($(this).val() == value || $(this).val() == "0")
thx

Comment: Ok, Thats worked:
if($(this).val() == value || value.includes('0')

Comment: That would match for a `0` _anywhere_ in the value - so for example for `12305` as well. Is that really what you want?

Comment: You are right ;) 
Thanx again :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

1. I use **change** instead of **input**
2. I changed the if to that `if($(this).val() == value || value=="0")`

```
        $('[name="zona_szam[]"]').on('change',function(){
          var value = $(this).val();
          $('[name="zona_szam[]"]').not(this).each(function(){
             if($(this).val() == value || value=="0") {
               $("#error").show();              
             }
          }) 
        });
```

Thanks for [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) for help ;)